# Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError in Spree::Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, spree

There are similar questions around, but many are very old and none have an answer for this specific scenario: Paperclip automatically installed by  Spree.

With Spree version `3.0.0`, the output of `gem list` shows:

```
cocaine (0.5.7)
paperclip (4.2.4)
```

What needs to be fixed:

```
Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError in Spree::Admin::ImagesController#create
```

I'm hoping to find out that I need to downgrade the `cocain` version... No dice yet.

Comment: no luck with 'paperclip', '4.2.1' 'cocaine', '0.5.5'

Comment: Do you have ImagMagic Installed? Also check libtool is also installed on your machine.

Comment: `identify` is installed by `imagemagick`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a problem with the images I was working with. I found out by trying to `identify` them in the command line.

```
identify poor-quality-image.png
```

It threw the same error.